# API Integration Docu Sign, Template Editor restrict user for creating the Recipients

Tags: docusignapi

We have integrated Docu Sign API. Where we give the option for the users of our product to create/edit the Template.

For this we open up, the Template Editor which shows the edit as below. Here the user is able to edit/delete/add new recipients. How can we restrict this?

[image: Dosusign Image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restrict this if you let them edit the template, you can only do that if you let them edit the envelope that was created from the template.
A DocuSign envelope/template has the following parts:

1. Documents.
2. Recipients.
3. Signing elements called tags or tabs

You are saying you want them to edit 1 and/or 3, but not 2, right?
So, to do that, you need to create an envelope, from the template, use fixed recipients that you set yourself, and let them go into the sender mode.

try this first from the web-app, without the API integration just to understand how it works. The envelope created from the template would initially has all the template documents and tabs, but the sender (which is your user) would be able to modify them, but not the recipients.